# Create new vector using another as an index to select data from a data frame

Tags: r

I have two data frames and am trying to create a vector composed of selections from the columns of a data frame using another vector as an index.

Here are two data frames as an illustrative sample:

```
PIN <- c("case1", "case2", "case3", "case4", "case5")
TS <- c("TS1", "TS4", "TS5", "TS1", "TS2")
index <- data.frame(PIN, TS)

PIN <- c("case1", "case2", "case3", "case4", "case5")
TS1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
TS2 <- c(6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
TS3 <- c(11, 12, 13, 14, 15)
TS4 <- c(16, 17, 18, 19, 20)
TS5 <- c(21, 22, 23, 24, 25)
data <- data.frame(PIN, TS1, TS2, TS3, TS4, TS5)
```

And the vector I'd like to create as an output is:

```
c(1, 17, 23, 4, 10)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sapply(1:NROW(index), function(i) data[i, as.character(index$TS[i])])
#[1]  1 17 23  4 10
```

OR

```
as.numeric(data[cbind(1:NROW(index), match(as.character(index$TS), names(data)))])
#[1]  1 17 23  4 10
```

Comment: Similar to second method: `data[-1][cbind(match(index$PIN, data$PIN), match(index$TS, names(data)[-1]))]`. Unsure which is preferable in terms of efficiency, but this one avoids `as.numeric` call.

Answer (score 0):

We can use vectorized option to extract the elements using `row/column` indexing.  Set the row names of the 'data' with the first column while subsetting it to remove the first column (`data[-1]`) and use the 'index' dataset to extract the elements with row/column names

```
`row.names<-`(data[-1], data[,1])[as.matrix(index)]
#[1]  1 17 23  4 10
```

---

Or another option is `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>%
    gather(key="TS", value, -PIN) %>% 
    right_join(., index) %>% 
   .$value
#[1]  1 17 23  4 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Not as elegant, but works:

```
diag(as.matrix(data[as.character(index$TS)]))
# [1]  1 17 23  4 10
```